# How to get bitbucket payload in Jenkins triggered by webhook

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops, webhooks

I've setup a bitbucket webhook which triggers if there are any PR opened

I'm successfully able to get the Jenkins job triggered but I'd want the payload from the request in my freestyle Jenkins job

I've tried using $BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD and it's returning null

I'd want the get the PR url from payload in the Jenkins as variable, kindly advice on this, thanks in advance: )